# Symfony 2: php.ini configuration checks seems not recognize php.ini values and says they are wrong

Tags: php, apache, symfony, config

Running the http://localhost:8000/config.php file, Symfony says that

> To enhance your Symfony experience, it’s recommended that you fix the following:
>
> - Set "xdebug.max_nesting_level" to e.g. "250" in php.ini* to stop Xdebug's infinite recursion protection erroneously throwing a fatal error in your project.
> - Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).
> - Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.
>
> Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini".

So i've done this in the php.ini and running phpinfo() all seems correctly set but the config.php continues to says that i have to make the editings.

Is there someone who can tell me why? Which checks should i do?

The php.ini file is the correct one as it is the one indicated by the config.php file and also the same loaded by PHP (phpinfo says that it is the same).

I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Have you reloaded MAMP after editing php.ini?

Comment: Yes, i restarted it. I also cleared the cache for the env=dev...

Comment: Anyway, i'm just trying again and now it seems to work.

The uniqe differenca is that i completely stopped MAMP and exit completely from it while to make the previous tests i simply stopped and restarted it.

So the solution seems to be to completely exit mamp, completely close it and then reopen it and restart the web server.

Thank you anyway for your reply smarber!